# php: how to save a sha1 raw hash in a cookie sha1($string, TRUE)

Tags: php, cookies, hash, passwords, sha1

Im trying to save a raw sha1 hash in a cookie but when I save it in a cookie I get a different string.

```
$password = "test";
$hashPassword = sha1($password, TRUE);
$cookie_userPassword= "cookie_userPassword";
$userPassword_value = $hashPassword;
setrawcookie($cookie_username, $userPassword_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
echo $_cookie_username;
```

in my code I save the hashed password in a database but the hashed password in the database is not the same as the hashed password in the cookie.

Comment: never put a passwword in a cookie, not even hashed

Comment: Also don't use SHA1 to hash passwords. Use `password_hash()`.

Comment: A raw hash value is not cookie safe..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're attempting to implement your own authentication/session system. As someone who has made this mistake before please take my well earned wisdom in this matter and don't. I know this is not the answer you're after and you just want to get your code working so you can move on to the next part. Please don't.

There are a number of functional and supported authentication libraries that have already taken the time to fully understand the security implications of an authentication system and done all the hard work for you.

As a personal recommendation I suggest you have a look at Sentinel (https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#installation) which can also handle the heavy lifting with registration and activation and a bunch of other things you'll probably find you'll need later on.

In regards to what you were attempting to do, the problem with putting a password (even hashed) in a cookie is that it is stored on the client's machine which means it's outside of your control. The hashed password should never leave your system. I think it would also be worth your while having a read through [PHP The Right Way - Password Hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing).